# Drawing Census Tracts in Google Maps

Tags: postgis, google-maps, google-maps-api, census, tiger

If I have census data with TigerGIS/PostGIS is it possible to get back all of the long/lat coordinates for the certain census tract? I want someone to be able to type in an address or census tract, and have it draw a shape on Google Maps around the corresponding census tract.

If I understood this correctly, Google Maps can highlight regions (draw shapes on the map) if I feed it a set of long/lat coordinates? I just need one census tract to be displayed.

Would that be the right line of thinking for solving this? Any suggestions to do something like this?

Comment: Yes, you are looking for [data layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)

Comment: Thanks that is great - what is the format I need to give Google Maps? I assume I need some function to run on the PostGIS database. Am I returning binary spatial data, or am I just returning long/lat coordinates in an array? Apologies if this is a dumb question!

Comment: a wms could do this

Comment: @iant if I wanted to avoid the WMS route, I should be ok though using the database directly to Google Maps right? I only need to show it for a certain region (not have it update in real time)

Comment: Depending on how complex your tracts are it might work but a WMS is easy to do and quick.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça This should be achievable without a WMS correct?

Comment: Yes. Wms is total overkill to load a single vector as you stated in the question. Geojson will work fine, as in the Google example

Comment: Thanks @JohnPowellakaBarça if you'd like to post your comment as an answer I will give you credit for it. Also, I would use http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html to get my data into the format google reads right?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way of doing it. Just moved house, chaos, so I'll write it up at some point when I get  a moment :-)